# JDeveloper 12.2.1.1 doesn't work in MacOS Sierra

Tags: oracle, jdeveloper, macos-sierra

Seems like JDeveloper doesn't work with macOS Sierra. I tried to reinstall, it didn't help. It just doesn't launch.
Is there some walkaround to solve the problem?
I tried also 12.2.1.0 version. The result is the same.

Upd. Setting Java home in product.conf doesn't help also.

```
Oracle JDeveloper 12c Development Build 12.2.1.1.0
 Copyright (c) 1997, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.osgi.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.resume(InternalSystemBundle.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.launch(Framework.java:664)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.EquinoxLauncher.internalInit(EquinoxLauncher.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.EquinoxLauncher.init(EquinoxLauncher.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.init(Equinox.java:178)
    at org.netbeans.modules.netbinox.Netbinox.init(Netbinox.java:84)
    at org.netbeans.core.netigso.Netigso.prepare(Netigso.java:167)
    at org.netbeans.NetigsoHandle.turnOn(NetigsoHandle.java:138)
    at org.netbeans.ModuleManager.enable(ModuleManager.java:1346)
    at org.netbeans.ModuleManager.enable(ModuleManager.java:1163)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.installNew(ModuleList.java:340)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.trigger(ModuleList.java:276)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleSystem.restore(ModuleSystem.java:301)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.getModuleSystem(Main.java:181)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.getModuleSystem(Main.java:150)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.start(Main.java:307)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.TopThreadGroup.run(TopThreadGroup.java:123)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.osgi.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.resume(InternalSystemBundle.java:225)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2.0"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.StateBuilder.createBundleDescription(StateBuilder.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.StateObjectFactoryImpl.createBundleDescription(StateObjectFactoryImpl.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.readStateData(BaseStorage.java:853)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.getStateManager(BaseStorage.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.getState(BaseAdaptor.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.frameworkStart(BaseStorage.java:923)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.frameworkStart(BaseAdaptor.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start(SystemBundleActivator.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which Java version do you have installed (java -version)?
Try removing the systemxxx directory (usually under .jdeveloper directory) and restarting JDeveloper.

Works for me fine on El Capitan

Answer (score 0):

If you did an OS update, the java home directory probably changed. Check the product.conf file in your .jdeveloper directory, and make sure the path to the JDK is correct

Comment: Did not help. I've updated my post with stacktrace after launching JDeveloper

Answer (score 0):

We need to remove **system_cache** folder only under path *<USER_HOME>/.jdeveloper/system12.2.x.x.x.x.x/system_cache*.
Please refer- https://migrmrz.wordpress.com/2016/08/29/jdeveloper-12c-wont-start-in-mac-os-x-el-capitan/